# How to change date format using jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, date, date-formatting

Today I want to transfrom date into different format using jQuery/Javascript :

```
$date = '2013-04-01T19:45:11.000Z'
$cool = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
```

How can I do that (PHP) in jQuery/Javascript ?

Thanks!

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: check solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546855/change-date-format-from-jquery?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a date in such format for javascript `Sun, 01 Sep 13 08:06:57 +0000`
So in PHP you need to do something like this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Perth');
echo date('D, d M y H:i:s')." +0000";
```

And you can experiment with jQuery to check it

```
$.get('dateformat.php', function(data) {
  date = new Date(data);
  console.log(date);  
});
```

Then you could format a date as you wish

**Example for formatting date object on your own:**

```
$.date = function(dateObj) {
    var d = new Date(dateObj);
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month < 10) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    return year + "." + month + "." + day;
};
```

**A jquery plugin to help you format a date similar to php**

https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

You can use it to apply a format like this

```
$.format.date("2009-12-18 10:54:50.546", "Test: dd/MM/yyyy")
```

I think that's it.

Comment: Why would you say you need that format for JavaScript?  That's just not true.  JavaScript supports a lot of different date formats natively.  [Here are some examples](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html)

Comment: Op indicated he wanted to use something like 'Y-m-d' that's why I referred to a plugin, otherwise I wrote an example how to do it by hand

Comment: I was referring to the first sentence of your answer.

Comment: @Dachi, I am trying to format date with jquery date format plugin but not succeeded. Can you please give me an example with jsfiddle link using https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat plugin.

Comment: @Dachi, Thank you very much for sparing your busy time. Is it possible to insert any static text in time format.
I am looking for a date format like Nov 15th @ 05a.m. I want 'th' after day of the month. 

How can i achieve this? 

I am using date format  $.format.date("2013-11-15 05:44:30.516", "MMM d @ hhp")

Comment: @rajeevprasanna sorry for late response. `MMM D @ hhp` is that way to go in that case. http://jsfiddle.net/dnatsvlishvili/JZLP3/1/

Answer (score 6):

Use the [javascript date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

```
<script>
  var date = new Date('2013-04-01T19:45:11.000Z');
  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  document.write(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
</script>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that .getMonth returns a zero based version of the month (January=0, February=1, December=11, etc). You should probably add one to the month if you are planning on returning a correct date this way: `var month = date.getMonth() + 1;`

Answer (score 2):

If you're aiming for newer browsers, then you can parse it directly in JavaScript like fujy or LeGrande showed.  But when you do, understand that the UTC date you passed will be converted to the local time zone of the browser.

If you want more flexibility, and full browser compatibility, then you should use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

```
// Parse it to a moment
var m = moment("2013-04-01T19:45:11.000Z");

// Format it in local time in whatever format you want
var s = m.format("YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss")

// Or treat it as UTC and then format it
var s = m.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is smart enough to accept dates in different format

```
var d1 = new Date('2013-04-01T19:45:11.000Z');
```

Comment: Well, most modern browsers are anyway.