# change date format from jquery

Tags: jquery, date, format

I have this date, that I get from jquery

```
Wed Oct 30 2013 09:05:17 GMT-0800 (Hora estándar Pacífico (México))
```

that I get this function

```
var date = new Date();
var newdate = new Date(date);
newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 7);
var nd = new Date(newdate);
$('#vigencia_receta_11').val(nd);
```

But I only need the date not the time, I want to format the date like this "DD/MM/YYYY"

Comment: I suggest using a date library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to do this.  `moment().add('days', 7).format('DD/MM/YYYY')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did like the following code:

```
function myDateFormatter ("pass your date here") {
        var d = new Date(dateObject);
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        if (day < 10) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        if (month < 10) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

        return date;
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

A couple of options.

If you're OK with including jQueryUI: `$("#vigencia_receta_11").val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/M/yy', nd));`

Otherwise, the jQuery [dateFormat plugin](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) does something similar: `$("#vigencia_receta_11").val($.format.date(nd, 'dd/M/yy'));`

Comment: Thanks the DateFormat plugin did the job.

Answer (score 2):

The date object has functions for getting access to the individual date components.  You can use:

```
$('#vigencia_receta_11').val((nd.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + nd.getDate() + "/" + nd.getFullYear());
```

Note that getMonth() returns a zero-indexed date, so you'll need to add 1 to get it to a human-readable date format.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setDate(sdate){
        var now = new Date(sdate);
        now.setDate(now.getDate()+3);
       
        var dd = now.getDate();
        var mm = now.getMonth() + 1;
        var y = now.getFullYear();

        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = "0" + dd;
        }
        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = "0" + mm;
        }

        var someFormattedDate = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
        $('#e-date').val(someFormattedDate);
    }
```