# json response date format to user defined date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Following code is returning `$("#dob")` and  `$("#anniversery")` date as `2014-04-01T00:00:00`

My code

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        function log(message) {
            $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
            $("#log").scrollTop(0);
        }
        $("#customerName").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajaxCustomer",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        str: $("#customerName").val(),
                        maxRows: 12
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.customerList, function(item) {
                            console.log(item);
                            return {
                                label: item.customerName,
                                value: item.customerName,
                                id: item.customerId,
                                address: item.address,
                                dob: item.dob,
                                mobno: item.mobno,
                                annversery: item.anniversery
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        alert(data.supplierList);
                        console.log(typeof data);
                        console.log(data);
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("#customerId").val(ui.item.id);
                $("#mobNo").val(ui.item.mobno);
                $("#address").val(ui.item.address);
                $("#dob").val(ui.item.dob);
                $("#anniversery").val(ui.item.annversery);
            },
            open: function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
            },
            close: function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want  $("#dob") and  $("#anniversery") its value in `yyyy/mm/dd` format
How to do this

I tried   `$("#dob").val(format_date(ui.item.dob));`

```
function format_date(dt) {

    var dd = dt.getDate();
    var mm = dt.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = dt.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    dt = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    document.write(dt);
    document.write(year + '/' + month + '/' + day);
}
```

This is not working.

Comment: Have a look at this url maybe it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546855/change-date-format-from-jquery

Comment: is it in `dateFormat` or `"2014-04-01T00:00:00"` (string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast the value you get from `ui.item.dob` to a *Date*.

```
var datefield = new Date(ui.item.dob);
$("#dob").val(format_date(datefield));
```

Then in your `format_date` function, remove the extra line at the bottom and put a return statement instead:

```
function format_date(dt) {

    var dd = dt.getDate();
    var mm = dt.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = dt.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    dt = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

Apply format :

```
$("#anniversery").text(moment(ui.item.annversery).format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = "2014-04-01T00:00:00";
var newDate = date.split("T")[0].replace(/-/g, "/");
console.log(newDate);

=> 2014/04/01
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create new Date object before using get functions:

```
var date = new Date(dt);
```

And then you can get the proper values:

```
var dd = date.getDate();
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As already @display_name pointed *you missed to parse the Date*.  Here a more simplified version of your code:

```
function format_date(dt) {
    var dateString = new Date(dt);  //parse the date
    var formatedDate = dateString.getFullYear() + "/" + 
                  ('0'+ (dateString.getMonth() +1)).slice(-2) + "/" + 
                  ('0'+ dateString.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return formatedDate; //return the formatted date to the input field
}
```

Now you can

```
$("#dob").val(format_date(ui.item.dob)); // incase if it is a textbox
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
var thisDate = "2013-01-01 00:00:00";
var thisDateT = thisDate.substr(0, 10);
```