# How to format the date coming from `Json` object in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, date

From ajax call I am getting `json` object. This object contain date value. I want to display it in `dd-mm-yyyy` format but it display as `Jun 4, 2014 12:00:00 AM` and in database(mysql) it stores as `2014-06-4`.

Here is  my jquery code.

```
$.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
  var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
  rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['vehicleno']); 
  rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['lat']); 
  rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['lng']); 
  rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['status']); 
  rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['rdate']); 
  rowNew.children().eq(5).text(value['rtime']); 
  rowNew.appendTo(table1);
});
```

Here `value['rdate']` and `value['rtime']` are date type of data. How to format it can any one help me in this.

Comment: Take a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546855/change-date-format-from-jquery

Comment: @RaNdoM_PoWneD Thank u , I used moment.js

Comment: What is the type of the date row in your SQL base?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

For date value,

```
wdm_date = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yyyy', value['rdate']);
```

For this, you will need to include jQuery UI library -

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```