# How to change into desired Date Format using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on asp.net project, I want to change the format of string date using jquery.
I'm getting the formatted date like `"07-MAY-99"` but I want to date like `"07/05/1999".`
how can I do this using jquery, can anyone help me ?

Comment: Could you please let us know what you've tried.. There are lot of solutions for this requirement.. Did you googled at least?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change date format from jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546855/change-date-format-from-jquery)

Comment: Please google, and dont ask duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method... as it is simple and custom created code.. I hope it works for you...

```js
var date = '07-MAY-99';
date = date.split('-');
var months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];

var newDate ='';
$.each(months, function(key,value){
   if(value == date[1])
   {
     var m = key+1;
     newDate = m+'/'+date['0']+'/'+date['2'];
   }
});
date = new Date(newDate)
alert(("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' +  date.getFullYear());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i need year in four digit can you edit your code ?

Comment: Great but still month and date should be in two digit.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) inmy projects. To me, it's really good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com) to achieve this:

```
var date = new Date('07-MAY-99');
var newDate = date.toString('dd-MM-yy');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use click [here] (http://www.datejs.com/) to achieve this:

```
var date = new Date('2014-01-06');
var newDate = date.toString('dd/MM/yy');
```

Comment: The second variant isn't going to work with authors format "07-MAY-99" --> "07/05/1999"
unless you have map month_names to month_numbers

Comment: @IgorTverdovskiy thanks I think I didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

Simply:)

Try to reconstruct DateTime string as like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="yourDatepickerId"/>   <!--Here is your DateTime picker-->
```

jQuery:

```
 var dateObj = $("#yourDatepickerId").val();  //<--Here is you get DateTime  value from picker

 var newDate = new Date(dateObj);
 var formattedString = [newDate.Date(),newDate.Month()+1,newDate.getFullYear()].join("/");

 alert(formattedString ); //Result : d/mm/yyyy
```